# CSS Word Wrap not applying to a react Typewriter plugin and more issues

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

So I have this section on my newly created React website/webapp. Currently, I am using [this react plugin on npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typewriter-effect) to create a typewriter effect on the text.

There are a few problems. The first being that the text (which bear in mind is in the same h2 tag), is on another line. I cannot figure out how to fix this for the life of me.

[image: what's happening]

Then, with long text/strings - it does not wrap the text properly (I want it to wrap the overhanging words onto a new line without affecting the width of the icon container below) - but it just doesn't do that either.

Here is my React code:

```html
<section className="Hero content"> {/* class 'content' is a content failsafe constraint. */}
                <Navbar />

                <div className="herocont">
                        <div className="discordpfp" />

                    <div className="textsect">
                        <div className="title">
                            <h1 className="maintext">Hi, I'm Psuedodoro</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div className="subtitle">
                            <h2 className="subtext">I'm a&nbsp; <Typewriter
                                    options={{
                                        autoStart: true,
                                        loop: true,
                                        cursor: '|',
                                        delay: 10,
                                        strings: ["FS Dev", "CS Student", "Discord Administrator", "UI/UX Designer", "VR Enthusiast"],
                                        wrapperClassName: 'typed-wrapper'
                                    }}
                                />
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div className="iconcont">
                            <div className="icons">
                                <FaGithub className="icon" />
                                <FaDiscord className="icon" />
                                <MdEmail className="icon" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <div className="waves1" />
```

And here is my (s)css:

```css
/* Stylesheet for the homepage */

h1, h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

b {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.herocont {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    margin-top: 5em;

    .discordpfp {
        border-radius: 100%;
        aspect-ratio: 1/1;
        height: 16em;
        background-image: url(../../../resources/discordpfp.png);
        
        /* Center the image in the div */
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
    }

    .textsect {
        display: inherit;
        margin-left: 7em;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-flow: column;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .maintext {
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }

    .subtitle {
        white-space: pre-line;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .iconcont {
        display: inherit;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 2em;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 3.5em;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background: hsla(206, 100%, 16%, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        
        .icons {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }

        .icon {
            aspect-ratio: 1/1;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-size: 2.5rem;
        }
    }
}

.waves1 {
    aspect-ratio: 3/2;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('../../../resources/SepHome2.svg');
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help you can give, I have been banging my head against the wall on this one!

Thanks,
Henry.

Answer (score 0):

The typewriter component is wrapped inside a div and divs by default `display:block`. So you could wrap the component by a span and make the span `display:inline-block` like

```
<span style={{display:"inline-block"}}>
  <TypewriterComponent>...</TypewriterComponent>
</span>
```

As for the resizing it's because the `iconfont` width is set to 100%, so when parent resizes due to the Typewriter component rendering it resizes too. You can set a max-width for the `iconfont` class or set a width that is not % based (px,em,rem).

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix can be to add `display: inline-flex` to your `h2` as here:

`<h2  style={{display: "inline-flex"}}>I'm a &nbsp;<Typewriter`

[You can see the result here](https://streamable.com/gmj8um)

As for the wrap issue, I only find it when I use the array feature with `strings` but using methods instead gives me the expected result....the only problem is you would have to split up your array (see code).  Or you could map your array and just reference items in typeString.

[See screen recording here](https://streamable.com/qe2m64)

```js
<Typewriter
  options={{
    autoStart: true,
    loop: false,
    delay: 0,
    cursor: "",
  }}
  onInit={(typewriter) => {
    typewriter
    .typeString('<div class="new">Discord Administrator Extra long text here</div>')
    .pauseFor(100)
    .deleteAll(50)
    .pauseFor(1000)
    .typeString("<div>VR ENTHUSIAST</div>")
      .start();
  }}
```